# How to limit video file duration with Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I need to limit video file duration in seconds with gst-launch-1.0, but didn't find any mentions of this feature in gstreamer documentation.
How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.